# Assuming convergence of the following series, find the value of $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...}}}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Assuming convergence of the following series, find the value of $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...}}}$

I was advised to proceed with this problem through substitution but that does not seem to help unless I am substituting the wrong parts. If i substitute the $6$, well then i am just stuck with above.

Any ideas on how to proceed. Also, what is the purpose of stating that it is convergent.

Comment: @GAVD I think this question quite is different from that one since it involves no  unknown, just a simple "evaluate this expression...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...}}}$, then observe that $x=\sqrt{6+x}$. Squaring both sides yields
$$
x^2=x+6
$$
, which is a quadratic formula. Solve it normally and choose the wise answer out of the 2 roots.

Comment: I see, so I would get -2 and 3. I would have to eliminate -2 since we cant have a negative number within the square root.

Comment: Exactly. I have a question that you might be interested in: What if BOTH roots are positive? Which one will you choose? :)

Comment: Interesting, I would say pick none but since its convergent, i would have to pick one? So i'm not sure.